# How can I replace kendoDropDownList text using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

```
$('#checkData').on('click', function()
{
    debugger;
    var dropdownlist = $("#droptext").data("kendoDropDownList");
    dropdownlist.dataItem().title = 'Apple';
    dropdownlist.refresh();
});
```

How can I replace `kendoDropDownList` text using jquery?

Comment: Are you trying to select a specific item in the dropdown, or are you trying to change the text of one of the items in the dropdown?

Comment: I am trying to change the text.

Comment: Your code seems to work: https://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/QxNJzq What problem exactly are you having?

Answer (score 1):

You can surely achieve that in databound.

```
dataBound: function(e) {
    var customData = [];
    var data = e.sender.dataSource._data;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i].ListItemSystemName == "AdmissionFee") {
            data[i].ListItemName = "One";
            data[i].ListItemSystemName = "One"
        }
        customData.push(data[i]);
    }
   $("#mydropdownList").data("kendoDropDownList").setDataSource(customData);
}
```